# How to count when a column has unique values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My file contains a column called 'Id';

eg:

```
Id  bill
---------
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   ccc
1   ddd
2   ee
```

I would like to return the count of Ids. Here it should be `count(data['Id')) = 3` (not 5)

`print(df.groupby('Id').count())` prints the whole file with rows count and column count. How can I make sure simple it prints how many unique Ids present in the column?

Comment: `df["Id"].nunique()`.

Comment: @HenryYik thanks this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original attempt just use the length of the returned dataframe using len()

```
print(len(df.groupby('Id').count()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
a = df["Id"].nunique()
print (a)
3
```

Or convert values to sets and get length:

```
a = len(set(df["Id"]))
print (a)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `collections.Counter`, assume `tmp` is your dataframe

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(tmp['Id'])
```